# Set Button Image in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, controltemplate

I have this Image Button in my WPF Application:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Play" Focusable="False" Width="100" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="PlayPauseButton" Click="PlayPauseButton_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="PlayPauseImage" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/PlayTube;component/images/PlayerApplication/PlayButton.png" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

And I want to have the ability to set the `Image` programmatically, but I can't access `PlayPauseImage`.

Any idea why it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `FindName`:

```
private void PlayPauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = (Image)PlayPauseButton.Template.FindName("PlayPauseImage", PlayPauseButton);
}
```

*`Note:`* Always use `FindName` only when the control will be fully loaded, otherwise it will not find it and give null.

Also for this event has:

[`ContentRendered for Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to locate control inside your `ControlTemplate`

```
var img = PlayPauseButton.Template.FindName("PlayPauseImage", PlayPauseButton) as Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `Button` is `Loaded`.. so its better to use the `Loaded` event to get this...

```
private void ButtonBase_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var image = PlayPauseButton.Template.FindName("PlayPauseImage", PlayPauseButton) as Image;
}
```